# How does gcc linker find boost libraries?

Tags: linux, gcc, boost, linker

I am getting started with the boost library for c++. Following the "getting started" steps [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#get-boost) , I download and install boost on my Linux system using install method under 5.1 (using b2), the path to boost is the default (/usr/local).

Under step 6 on the link above, there is an example code with different ways of linking to the boost binaries. For example, they suggest:

```
$ c++ -I path/to/boost_1_77_0 example.cpp -o example \
-L~/boost/stage/lib/ -lboost_regex-gcc34-mt-d-1_36
```

However, I can compile and link simply with:

```
$ g++ example.cpp -o example
```

In order to see what the linker is doing (why I don't need to include lib paths) I run

```
$ g++ -v example.cpp -Wl,--verbose
```

with the following output:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-9-Av3uEd/gcc-9-9.4.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/cc1plus -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE boost_test.cpp -quiet -dumpbase boost_test.cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase boost_test -version -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -o /tmp/cc2yx4Ya.s
GNU C++14 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) version 9.4.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 9.4.0, GMP version 6.2.0, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.22.1-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/9
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9
 /usr/include/c++/9/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++14 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) version 9.4.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 9.4.0, GMP version 6.2.0, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.22.1-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 65fe925b83d3956b533de4aaba7dace0
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v --64 -o /tmp/ccMXwlld.o /tmp/cc2yx4Ya.s
GNU assembler version 2.34 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccqtwmCa.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -pie -z now -z relro /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../.. /tmp/ccMXwlld.o --verbose -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34
  Supported emulations:
   elf_x86_64
   elf32_x86_64
   elf_i386
   elf_iamcu
   elf_l1om
   elf_k1om
   i386pep
   i386pe
using internal linker script:
==================================================
/* Script for -pie -z combreloc -z separate-code -z relro -z now */
/* Copyright (C) 2014-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   Copying and distribution of this script, with or without modification,
   are permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright
   notice and this notice are preserved.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf64-x86-64", "elf64-x86-64",
          "elf64-x86-64")
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386:x86-64)
ENTRY(_start)
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib");
SECTIONS
{
  PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0)); . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  .interp         : { *(.interp) }
  .note.gnu.build-id  : { *(.note.gnu.build-id) }
  .hash           : { *(.hash) }
  .gnu.hash       : { *(.gnu.hash) }
  .dynsym         : { *(.dynsym) }
  .dynstr         : { *(.dynstr) }
  .gnu.version    : { *(.gnu.version) }
  .gnu.version_d  : { *(.gnu.version_d) }
  .gnu.version_r  : { *(.gnu.version_r) }
  .rela.dyn       :
    {
      *(.rela.init)
      *(.rela.text .rela.text.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.t.*)
      *(.rela.fini)
      *(.rela.rodata .rela.rodata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.r.*)
      *(.rela.data .rela.data.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.d.*)
      *(.rela.tdata .rela.tdata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.td.*)
      *(.rela.tbss .rela.tbss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.tb.*)
      *(.rela.ctors)
      *(.rela.dtors)
      *(.rela.got)
      *(.rela.bss .rela.bss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.b.*)
      *(.rela.ldata .rela.ldata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.l.*)
      *(.rela.lbss .rela.lbss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.lb.*)
      *(.rela.lrodata .rela.lrodata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.lr.*)
      *(.rela.ifunc)
    }
  .rela.plt       :
    {
      *(.rela.plt)
      *(.rela.iplt)
    }
  . = ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE));
  .init           :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.init)))
  }
  .plt            : { *(.plt) *(.iplt) }
.plt.got        : { *(.plt.got) }
.plt.sec        : { *(.plt.sec) }
  .text           :
  {
    *(.text.unlikely .text.*_unlikely .text.unlikely.*)
    *(.text.exit .text.exit.*)
    *(.text.startup .text.startup.*)
    *(.text.hot .text.hot.*)
    *(SORT(.text.sorted.*))
    *(.text .stub .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
    /* .gnu.warning sections are handled specially by elf.em.  */
    *(.gnu.warning)
  }
  .fini           :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.fini)))
  }
  PROVIDE (__etext = .);
  PROVIDE (_etext = .);
  PROVIDE (etext = .);
  . = ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE));
  /* Adjust the address for the rodata segment.  We want to adjust up to
     the same address within the page on the next page up.  */
  . = SEGMENT_START("rodata-segment", ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) + (. & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1)));
  .rodata         : { *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*) }
  .rodata1        : { *(.rodata1) }
  .eh_frame_hdr   : { *(.eh_frame_hdr) *(.eh_frame_entry .eh_frame_entry.*) }
  .eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RO { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) *(.eh_frame.*) }
  .gcc_except_table   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.gcc_except_table .gcc_except_table.*) }
  .gnu_extab   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.gnu_extab*) }
  /* These sections are generated by the Sun/Oracle C++ compiler.  */
  .exception_ranges   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.exception_ranges*) }
  /* Adjust the address for the data segment.  We want to adjust up to
     the same address within the page on the next page up.  */
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE), CONSTANT (COMMONPAGESIZE));
  /* Exception handling  */
  .eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RW { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) *(.eh_frame.*) }
  .gnu_extab      : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.gnu_extab) }
  .gcc_except_table   : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.gcc_except_table .gcc_except_table.*) }
  .exception_ranges   : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.exception_ranges*) }
  /* Thread Local Storage sections  */
  .tdata      :
   {
     PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__tdata_start = .);
     *(.tdata .tdata.* .gnu.linkonce.td.*)
   }
  .tbss       : { *(.tbss .tbss.* .gnu.linkonce.tb.*) *(.tcommon) }
  .preinit_array    :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  }
  .init_array    :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.init_array.*) SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.ctors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtbegin.o *crtbegin?.o *crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .ctors))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  }
  .fini_array    :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.fini_array.*) SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.dtors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtbegin.o *crtbegin?.o *crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .dtors))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  }
  .ctors          :
  {
    /* gcc uses crtbegin.o to find the start of
       the constructors, so we make sure it is
       first.  Because this is a wildcard, it
       doesn't matter if the user does not
       actually link against crtbegin.o; the
       linker won't look for a file to match a
       wildcard.  The wildcard also means that it
       doesn't matter which directory crtbegin.o
       is in.  */
    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.ctors))
    KEEP (*crtbegin?.o(.ctors))
    /* We don't want to include the .ctor section from
       the crtend.o file until after the sorted ctors.
       The .ctor section from the crtend file contains the
       end of ctors marker and it must be last */
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .ctors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.ctors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.ctors))
  }
  .dtors          :
  {
    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*crtbegin?.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .dtors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.dtors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.dtors))
  }
  .jcr            : { KEEP (*(.jcr)) }
  .data.rel.ro : { *(.data.rel.ro.local* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.local.*) *(.data.rel.ro .data.rel.ro.* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.*) }
  .dynamic        : { *(.dynamic) }
  .got            : { *(.got.plt) *(.igot.plt) *(.got) *(.igot) }
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_RELRO_END (0, .);
  .data           :
  {
    *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d.*)
    SORT(CONSTRUCTORS)
  }
  .data1          : { *(.data1) }
  _edata = .; PROVIDE (edata = .);
  . = .;
  __bss_start = .;
  .bss            :
  {
   *(.dynbss)
   *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
   *(COMMON)
   /* Align here to ensure that the .bss section occupies space up to
      _end.  Align after .bss to ensure correct alignment even if the
      .bss section disappears because there are no input sections.
      FIXME: Why do we need it? When there is no .bss section, we do not
      pad the .data section.  */
   . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 64 / 8 : 1);
  }
  .lbss   :
  {
    *(.dynlbss)
    *(.lbss .lbss.* .gnu.linkonce.lb.*)
    *(LARGE_COMMON)
  }
  . = ALIGN(64 / 8);
  . = SEGMENT_START("ldata-segment", .);
  .lrodata   ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) + (. & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1)) :
  {
    *(.lrodata .lrodata.* .gnu.linkonce.lr.*)
  }
  .ldata   ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) + (. & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1)) :
  {
    *(.ldata .ldata.* .gnu.linkonce.l.*)
    . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 64 / 8 : 1);
  }
  . = ALIGN(64 / 8);
  _end = .; PROVIDE (end = .);
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_END (.);
  /* Stabs debugging sections.  */
  .stab          0 : { *(.stab) }
  .stabstr       0 : { *(.stabstr) }
  .stab.excl     0 : { *(.stab.excl) }
  .stab.exclstr  0 : { *(.stab.exclstr) }
  .stab.index    0 : { *(.stab.index) }
  .stab.indexstr 0 : { *(.stab.indexstr) }
  .comment       0 : { *(.comment) }
  .gnu.build.attributes : { *(.gnu.build.attributes .gnu.build.attributes.*) }
  /* DWARF debug sections.
     Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
     of the section so we begin them at 0.  */
  /* DWARF 1 */
  .debug          0 : { *(.debug) }
  .line           0 : { *(.line) }
  /* GNU DWARF 1 extensions */
  .debug_srcinfo  0 : { *(.debug_srcinfo) }
  .debug_sfnames  0 : { *(.debug_sfnames) }
  /* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2 */
  .debug_aranges  0 : { *(.debug_aranges) }
  .debug_pubnames 0 : { *(.debug_pubnames) }
  /* DWARF 2 */
  .debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*) }
  .debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
  .debug_line     0 : { *(.debug_line .debug_line.* .debug_line_end) }
  .debug_frame    0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
  .debug_str      0 : { *(.debug_str) }
  .debug_loc      0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
  .debug_macinfo  0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }
  /* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions */
  .debug_weaknames 0 : { *(.debug_weaknames) }
  .debug_funcnames 0 : { *(.debug_funcnames) }
  .debug_typenames 0 : { *(.debug_typenames) }
  .debug_varnames  0 : { *(.debug_varnames) }
  /* DWARF 3 */
  .debug_pubtypes 0 : { *(.debug_pubtypes) }
  .debug_ranges   0 : { *(.debug_ranges) }
  /* DWARF Extension.  */
  .debug_macro    0 : { *(.debug_macro) }
  .debug_addr     0 : { *(.debug_addr) }
  .gnu.attributes 0 : { KEEP (*(.gnu.attributes)) }
  /DISCARD/ : { *(.note.GNU-stack) *(.gnu_debuglink) *(.gnu.lto_*) }
}


==================================================
/usr/bin/ld: mode elf_x86_64
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtbeginS.o succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtbeginS.o
attempt to open /tmp/ccMXwlld.o succeeded
/tmp/ccMXwlld.o
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libstdc++.so succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libstdc++.so
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libm.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libm.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so succeeded
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 succeeded
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmvec.so.1 succeeded
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmvec.so.1
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so succeeded
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so
attempt to open libgcc_s.so.1 failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so.1 failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.a succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.a
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.a succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.a
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libc.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so succeeded
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 succeeded
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a succeeded
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a
(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a)elf-init.oS
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 succeeded
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so succeeded
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so
attempt to open libgcc_s.so.1 failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so.1 failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.a succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.a
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.a succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.a
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtendS.o succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtendS.o
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
libm.so.6 needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libstdc++.so
found libm.so.6 at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libstdc++.so
found ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
```

However, there is no indication of the linker attempting to open any boost library in the output above? So I am wondering, how does gcc manage to link this executable? Does anyone know of some good tutorials for linkers, or reading material?

Thanks!

Comment: Use [ldd(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html) and [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), see [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and read Levine's book on [Linkers and loaders](https://www.elsevier.com/books/linkers-and-loaders/levine/978-0-08-051031-6). Read also the [Program Library HowTo](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/)

Comment: A lot of [Boost](https://www.boost.org/) -but not all- are header only libraries

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thanks for the links! Also, in this particular example, the library is separate binary to be added during linking phase.